# Counting elements in Ionic

Tags: angular, filter, ionic3

I use this to filter my elements

```
this.filteredParticipants = this.participantsList.valueChanges().map(res => res.filter(guest => (guest.name.toLowerCase() + " " + guest.surname.toLowerCase()).includes(term.toLowerCase())));
```

and it works like a charm.

I also need to count elements with a certain property, I thought something like this

```
this.participantsList.valueChanges().map(res => res.filter(guest => {if(guest.paid) {this.n=this.n+1}}));
```

where n is a number. It doesn't work. Someone can explain how I can reach my target? Thanks

Comment: "Doesn't work" ? Please add the error you get to your question

Comment: I don't get any error, the app works, but n does not increase.

Comment: `this.participantsList.valueChanges().map(res => res.filter(guest => guest.paid).length);` ?

Comment: Nope, then I can't assign it to a number.

Comment: So `n` should be the total count of items with property `guest.paid`? Your question would benefit if you provide more details, especially of what your desired result should be.

Comment: I want to count how many partecipants have paid. I've got an AngularFireList<any> and I get the Obeservable<any[]> from this.allParticipants = this.participantsList.valueChanges();. Then I want to count over that object in some way, I can't understand how.